# In Powerapps, Can I add a text field and connect it to a SharePoint list column

Tags: powerapps

In Power apps, Can I add a text field and connect it to a SharePoint list column.

I am trying to create an app, with power apps controls and then attaching them to SharePoint columns rather than binding the columns to the app.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

On the TextInput control, you can add an expression on the Default property to display the data from a SharePoint list column.  However the TextInput control can only show the value from one record, so I typically use a Gallery or DataTable control to select the record.  Then the TextInput control can bind to the selected record's field.

1. Add a Vertical Gallery
2. Set the Gallery1 DataSource to the SharePoint List
3. Add a TextInput control
4. Set the TextInput1 Default property to the selected record's field name

   ```
   Default=Gallery1.Selected.Title
   ```